# How to integrate correctly Ionic Capacitor with an existing Angular 7 web application

Tags: angular, ionic4, capacitor

We have an Angular 7 client that consumes a RESTful Web API Core 3.1 service.

Our Angular folder structure is pretty simple and taken from here:
https://itnext.io/choosing-a-highly-scalable-folder-structure-in-angular-d987de65ec7.

We integrated Capacitor (Ionic) into our project, and a lot of the native functionality is managed within the same code base which causes some messy behavior, for example, we used to have a loading screen like this:

app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<ng-container *ngIf="!isAppLoaded">
 <div id="loader">
 </div>
</ng-container>
```

app.component.ts

```
if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
  this.isAppLoaded = true;
}
```

Now that we have a mobile app (thanks to Capacitor), the loading behavior is managed with a splash screen and hiding of the splash screen is done inside app.component.ts like this:

```
if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
  this.isAppLoaded = true;
  SplashScreen.hide();
}
```

Note that SplashScreen is imported at the top of the file.

We are looking for a best practice approach for how to manage this plugins or native functionally inside our code base without causing a mess.